# How to query page response time using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to query a metric I found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

The metric I'm looking to query is called `displayed_message_response_time`.

What would I need to put into the Facebook API query field to pull this data up for a particular page?

I've tried this:

```
GET->  /v2.6/pageid/displayed_message_response_time
```

Sadly, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /displayed_message_response_time",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "someid"
  }
}
```

Anyone know the proper way to query this metric?

Comment: That is not how you ask for a field

Comment: @wizkid Can you please share the proper way to query this field?

Comment: Like any other field

Comment: @WizKid when I query this field it just returns "automatic" as a string, what can I query for to return a numeric value?

Comment: No. JSON doesn't handle numbers very well so they are returned as strings

Comment: @Wizkid I see. Would you happen to know a metric that I can query instead to return a numeric value? I was looking at this, https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-measure-average-response-time-for-Facebook-pages . The one answer by Rich says there's a metric for response time measured in minutes and averaged durin past 7 days. UNfortunately he doesn't say the metric name, I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Oh sorry. Just ignore what I said. It returns automatic because you have a welcome message. So there is no time metric.

Comment: @WizKid Can you please expand on that? meaning, if I remove the "welcome message" then it'll display the time averaged into 7 days? or Is there another metric for this exact thing?

Comment: Yes. If you have a welcome message that will be displayed directly so there is nothing to measure.

Comment: @WizKid Thanks for all of your help so far. I really appreciate it. Is there anyway you can tell me how to disable welcome messages? Where would I go to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your query like this:

```
/pageid?fields=displayed_message_response_time
```

This should return what you're looking for.